# How to typeset the short vowel, the long vowel, and the pause symbols used in Sanskrit/Marathi metres?

Tags: symbols, indic, metre

Sanskrit, and one of its derivatives, Marathi, have a rich literary history of various poetic metres. Like several other languages, they have notations for the *short vowel*, the *long vowel*, and the *pause* to annotate the lines of a metrical poem that aids its recitation. See [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtknF.png) for an example in which the short vowels are shown (for clarity) in red squares, long vowels in green squares, and pauses in blue squares. Such an annotation, which is simply a sequence of these symbols, could be placed above or below the text. In the example shown, the annotation is placed above the text.

I see a `metre` package in CTAN that has some similarities (e.g. Ties) with the symbols I am looking for, but they are not the same.

Has anyone attempted to standardize these for Sanskrit in `LaTeX`? If not, how may one go about it? I am not yet too well-versed with the development of a package.

### A Print Example

[image]

Comment: The simplest answer is to use an OpenType Devanagari font that contains all the accents you need, such as Shobhika, and enter them in Unicode.

Comment: I searched for the unicode code point for these characters which relate to accenting, but I don't think Unicode assigns them to these three symbols in the 6.0 Spec. I might register a request for inclusion. Do you know?

Comment: Unicode 6 is from 2011. Check the [Devanagari Extended block](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA8E0.pdf) and [Vedic extensions](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1CD0.pdf) in the current spec, or search for them in your character map app.

Comment: Officially, I think you’re only supposed to do this for Latin transliteration, but the breve (U+0306) and macron (U+0304) might work on Devanagari in some font.

Comment: They aren't in the devanaagarii extensions or vedic extensions. I might consider the breve and macron, but that leaves the pause character alone. Thanks!

Comment: What glyph would make a good pause? I'm thinking maybe `"`. Alternatively, one could be built manually (perhaps via one of `DeclareText...` commands), using boxes and raise/lower and kerning etc. In Latin/Greek prosody, `|` is a pause/break, I think.

Comment: I guess the pause is different from a ". We need to standardize this soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and long are in `metre` package (it uses OT1 encoding, though). A pause could be added, with more or less work according to which font/glyph it should be.

The much more recent `metrix` package also has long and short. It is built on TikZ and has many commands, settings and options.

[image: example packages]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{metre}
\usepackage{metrix}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fdeva{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\tikzset{
every metrix syllable node/.append style={font=\fdeva},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\rowcolor{blue!5}
\bfseries Package & \bfseries Example \\
\hline
 & \fdeva दयानिधी \\
 & \\
metre & \fdeva \begin{metrica} \-द\={या}\-{नि}\={धी} \end{metrica}\\
& \\
metrix & \metrics[2+4={colored highlight}]{u _ u _ }{द-या-नि-धी} \\
metrix & 
\tikzset{every superscript picture/.style={
baseline=1ex,
}}
\setmetrixvar{symbolshift}{-0.6em} 
\metrics[2=colored highlight,4={colored highlight,superscript=^^^^030b}]{u _ u _ }{द-या-नि-धी} \\
& \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

`metrix` has a pause (a `,` input produces `|`) but is ignored at the end of strings (for obvious reasons), so the one word example is not long enough.

---

*Addendum*

Glyph U+030B (combining double acute accent), raised or lowered as appropriate,  could function as a placeholder for the pausemark, until a standard one is designed.

[image: placeholder pausemark]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{metre}
\usepackage{metrix}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fdeva{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\newcommand\pausemark{\lower2.3em\hbox{^^^^030b}}
\tikzset{
every metrix syllable node/.append style={font=\fdeva},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\rowcolor{blue!5}
\bfseries Package & \bfseries Example \\
\hline
 & \fdeva दयानिधी \\
 & \\
metre & \fdeva \begin{metrica} \-द\={या}\-{नि}\={धी} \end{metrica}\\
& \\
metrix & \metrics[2=colored highlight,4={colored highlight,superscript={\pausemark}},9={superscript={\pausemark}}]{u _ u _ u u u u _}{द-या-नि-धी ल-ल ल-ल-ला} \\
metrix & 
\tikzset{every superscript picture/.style={
baseline=1ex,
}}
\setmetrixvar{symbolshift}{-0.6em} 
\metrics[2=colored highlight,4={colored highlight,superscript=^^^^030b}]{u _ u _ }{द-या-नि-धी} \\
& \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```